# C++ Platform specific includes

Tags: c++

I'm working on a multi-platform project. I want a simple and quick way of managing OS-specific includes, preferably without any external tools.

I would like something like this (which I'm well aware won't work)

```
#define PLATFORM_A 1
#define PLATFORM_B 2

#ifndef TARGET_PLATFORM
//ERROR
#endif

#if TARGET_PLATFORM == PLATFORM_A
    #define DIR "a"
#elif TARGET_PLATFORM == PLATFORM_B
    #define DIR "b"

#define PLATFORM_INCLUDE(file) \
    #include "platforms/" DIR "/" file
```

Comment: That would work if your Makefile, generated by a configure command, injects those constants. For example, if you're on linux, your Makefile would have `gcc -DPLATFORM=windows` and so on. However, the question is what are you trying to do? A Win32 API program for example wouldn't be distributed in the same source tree as a Qt program, but if you're trying to do sockets, your source file might be littered with #if conditionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have same file tree for different platfroms you could specify only file name for include file in the source code and use platform dependent include directory. This directory could be easily configured by environment variable.

Comment: That would be the perfect solution for our current setup. Why didn't I think of that? :P

Answer (score 5):

One set up I see fairly frequently is as follows:

```
// platform.h

#if defined PLATFORM_A
    #include "platform_a.h"
#elif defined PLATFORM_B
    #include "platform_b.h"
#else
    // #pragma error or whatever
#endif
```

Then `#include "platform.h"` where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can have preprocessor directives defined by the platform itself. In this way you can use:

```
#ifndef MAC // MAC performs #define MAC

#ifndef WINDOWS // Windows performs #define WINDOWS

#ifndef UNIX // Unix performs #define UNIX

// ERROR

#endif

#endif

#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using + between your strings. That should be the C++ syntax.

So something like:

```
#define PLATFORM_INCLUDE(file) \
    #include "platforms/" + DIR + "/" file
```

Comment: This is at preprocessor time.  Juxtaposition is how to get string literal concatenation here, not C++ std::string operators.

Comment: But that wouldn't work as it would require multiple passes of the preprocessor, or am I completely wrong?